# If $ \lim_{x \to + \infty} f'(x) = + \infty $, then $ \lim_{x \to + \infty} f(x) = + \infty $

Tags: real-analysis

$ f $ is a differentiable function on the interval $ [a, + \infty) $ with $ a \in \mathbb{R} $

Prove that if $ \lim_{x \to + \infty} f'(x) = + \infty $, then $ \lim_{x \to + \infty} f(x) = + \infty $

---

$ f $ is a differentiable function on the interval $ [a, + \infty) $, so by the mean value theorem we have:

$ \exists c \in (a,x): f'(c) = \frac{f(x) - f(a)}{x-a}$

$\implies f(x) = f(a) + (x-a)f'(c)$

$\implies\lim_{x \to +\infty} f(x) = \lim_{x \to +\infty}(x-a)f'(c) + f(a) $

I don't know how to proceed to prove $ \lim_{x \to + \infty} f'(c) = + \infty $ because we have: $ a < c < x $. Thank you.

Comment: What if you choose $b\ge a$ so that $f'(z)\ge M$ for all $z\ge b$?

Comment: Hint: there is a $b > a$ such as $t>b \rightarrow f'(t) > 1$. Now integrate for $t\in [b,x]$.

Comment: Hint: It suffices to assume that $f'(x)\geqslant1$ for every $x\geqslant x_0$ since then, $f(x)\geqslant x+f(x_0)-x_0$ and the limit of the RHS is $+\infty$.